# Velocity of car down an Inclined Plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity

I was learning to make a car game and came across this situation where my car is on an inclined plane. It's initial velocity is 0. Now, the problem is that my memory serves me this formula to calculate the final velocity 
$$v_f^2 - v_i^2 = 2as$$
Since, $v_i = 0$, the equation would be
$$v_f^2 = 2as$$
For an inclined plane $a = g \sin \theta$, 
$$ \Rightarrow v_f^2 = 2 g s \sin \theta $$

However, my memory doesn't serve me what to do when you do not know how far the car would have to travel on this inclined plane.

My problem in short:

$\bullet$ I need to add Velocity to the car which is on the inclined plane

$\bullet$ What is the formula I should use? does the formula mentioned above of any good in this case?

$\bullet$ If yes, how would I come over this displacement drawback (drawback in the sense, I would not know how far the car would travel)

$\bullet$ If no, what would you use to add the velocity to the car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your problem in terms of what is the velocity of the car at any instant of time after it started. The answer is $v = a_{\rm eff} t$ from the first kinematical equation. In the same time, the car would've traveled a distance $s = (1/2)a_{\rm eff} t^2$ from the second kinematical equation.

The other option is - if your inclined plane is of any fixed length $L$ and the time $t$ of concern to you is the time in which it has completely traversed the plane, you can cast everything in terms of this distance, by using the second of these equations to write $t_f = (2L/a_{\rm eff})^{1/2}$, and $v_f = a_{\rm eff} t_f$.

Thus, in order to model everything perfectly, you need to have one of these as inputs - either $L$, or the instant of time $t$.

Comment: I can get the time since the vehicle started moving, not an issue. Now, what if the plane is no more inclined? Will this formula be still valid?

Comment: @gameOne - No more inclined means? The end of ramp? Yes, the formula still applies, only the effective acceleration changes (to zero)!

Comment: @gameOne - Use the formula to find the $v_f$ at the end of the incline. Thereafter, its no longer going down the incline (or say, $\theta = 0$), so it is uniform motion with zero acceleration after that. If you want to simulate the real world in reality, you can take into account friction, which will add some retardation, but if you haven't covered it on the inlcline, no point in doing it on the ground either. So, uniform motion.

Comment: I get it. When the car is on a horizontal plane the velocity due to inclination would be zero. Fine. However, I'm struggling to understand how do I autually out this into code. If, I get the input from user to apply speed, I would have v = a*t + user_input; and a = g*Sinx t = time since velocity is not 0. I would reset this as soon as the inclination would be 0. Right?
Or should I reset this when the velocity is 0?

Comment: The velocity at the end of ramp would be whatever it acquired during the fall (at the end of the fall), which is $v_f$ according to the formula. Now, this is your input for the horizontal motion.

Comment: does t become zero when the inclination is 0? I kind of didnt get the role of t

Comment: @gameOne - Lets say the car started from rest at the top of the incline at time $t=0$. It reached the end of the ramp at time $t={t_f}_1$, where it had $v = v_f$ calculated above. Now, your clock is still ticking and time is still running. At all times after $t=t_{f_1}$, car has a uniform motion. So, at any time $t_2$ in the future, $v(t_2) = v_f$ still, same as what was calculated above. Clock keeps ticking :)

Comment: Well, say if i apply brakes to the car when it is on another inclined plane. The t would still be ticking as you mentioned. Now using the formula, wont I get a different value of speed (one which is more than what I got in the first case, while it was in rest)??

Comment: When you apply brakes, the car stops and $v=0$ for as long as it is braked. But this is not the same as what I had described earlier, when it reaches the end of the ramp, that's not the same as braking, it will continue to move along the horizontal ground, with whatever velocity it had acquired while it was on the ramp.

Comment: so is it safe to assume that I need to reset the value of t when the velocity is 0?

Comment: In _that_ sense, yes. Because when the driver gets his foot away from the brake, it is as good as starting from 0 again. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. Kindly do a favor for me. Upvote the below answer as it was helpful for me and I am yet to earn enough reputation to upvote...

Comment: @gameOne - Sure. Done :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, you seem to not know the displacement of the car but you still need to increase the velocity of the car.

Velocity of the car has to be expressed in terms of a quantity. I suggest you use velocity as a function of time,

$$v_f = v_i + at$$ 
$a = g \sin \theta $ as you told correctly. So 
$$v_f = v_i + g \sin \theta t$$

With my limited programming knowledge I'm guessing that it is easier to count time rather than displacement.

Comment: I kind of understand, but what if the car moved from an inclined plane and is now on a horizontal plane. What would I do then?
Is there a standard formula which takes into consideration both the situations?

Comment: Well there would be no acceleration for the car unless it can speed up too. So its velocity after crossing the incline will remain same unless friction acts